# Drawback of using your logo for animations

Tags: logo, animation, branding

I am considering using an animation during which my company’s logo morphs and changes color (company colors).
I’m not sure if it is good for your image and brand recognition.
What are potential problems I should consider in this respect?

**Context**

Our logo has 'music' in it's name. For the animation the word music changes to a number of genres until it finishes on 'music' (like the logo) to show a diversity in music genres used in our company.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your question to make it less opinion-based and more answerable (there are almost certainly some branding guidelines somewhere that cover this, but this doesn’t help you; at the end of the day, you have to decide yourself; we can only help you to consider all the relevant arguments). Pleas check whether everything is still reflects your intentions. It would also help if you could [edit] your question to add more context, such as why and in which context you want to do this.

Comment: Makes sense! I've edited my question to provide context.

Answer (score 2):

If all of these things are true:

- The logo [has the qualities of a good logo](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/27/23061) (including [working in greyscale](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/85781/23061)).
- The logo is not dependent on the animation to give the desired impression.
- The animation itself fits the desired branding (see [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/240/23061) for the difference between logos and branding).
- The animation itself is of good quality (a whole other post could be made defining exactly what "good quality" encompasses) and used in only appropriate settings.

I can't think of any drawbacks.

Answer (score 1):

> I’m not sure if it is good for your image and brand recognition.

Neither are we, as we don't know what your brand is, what industry you are in, what context you are using the animation in, who your competition is, etc.

In other words, context is everything.

There are, of course, plenty of animated logos. Nearly every film distributor has one. Netflix has one. NFL. Etc.

Like a static logo, all that matters is that a) it's done well and b) takes into consideration the context it will be used in.

Answer (score 0):

***Do not*** DECONSTRUCT your logo.

Rather, have the dynamic components of your logo come together to FORM your corporate identity at the conclusion of your message not to introduce the segment.

I learned years ago the benefit of not "destroying" your logo and the benefit of ENDING your message with the appearance of your logo complete and intact to punctuate your message. The concept to search is "primacy and recency."

Your logo must appear to be lasting; so, it is fitting that it ends your message.

Put yourself together, don't take yourself apart — even metaphorically.

Here's the full sequence that you'll see in different forms for every pitch. First, frame your product by using cultural "cues" familiar to your target audience. Then, use the body of your "message" to sell your fish. Finally, identify yourself to the audience.

If you do otherwise, you invite part of your "as-yet-unfamiliar" market segment to adopt a "That doesn't apply to me" attitude. You've lost time trying to do two things at once, introduce the brand before its relevance to you, and then the brand relevance. We don't think that way. Even the best brand in the world shows you enjoying the drink before you see their logo and they NEVER take apart the logo. You don't even see the obvious signature being written by animation.